# ssh using id not working, falling back to password

Tags: openssh

I have done `ssh-copy-id` from my local to remote machine, and the remote machine does show `.ssh/authorised_keys`.
But, when I am trying to do `ssh remote` its falling back to password.

Here is the bottom of the log (removed the top part as it contains lot of keys and ip)

```
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key:  <HEX Key>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/rudra/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/rudra/.ssh/known_hosts:63
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <ip of the remote machine>
debug1: Host '<ip of the remote machine>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/rudra/.ssh/known_hosts:63
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:/<KEY> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:)


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xT3VPQUunB3Nv/Pmi6C6Sroc0fa9SlKcQ4d0eF2vxzI agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/rudra/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Can someone kindly help on the reason?

In remote, I have:

```
ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

locally I have:

```
ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  FIPS 16 Feb 2021
```

`/etc/sshd_config` from remote is:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

This is `50-redhat.conf`, which is the only thing uncommented in local `ssh_config`

```
# The options here are in the "Match final block" to be applied as the last
# options and could be potentially overwritten by the user configuration
Match final all
    # Follow system-wide Crypto Policy, if defined:
    Include /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config

    GSSAPIAuthentication yes

# If this option is set to yes then remote X11 clients will have full access
# to the original X11 display. As virtually no X11 client supports the untrusted
# mode correctly we set this to yes.
    ForwardX11Trusted yes

# Send locale-related environment variables
    SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
    SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
    SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
    SendEnv XMODIFIERS

# Uncomment this if you want to use .local domain
# Host *.local
```

Comment: Why are you using such an archaic version on the server there is a good chance that’s the problem

Comment: This is on a cluster, that is not updated. I am persuing them for update but not sure if I will succeed. I have ssh from 2013, vi 7.6 and so on.... But its not under my control.

Answer (score 0):

Check `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` on both `sshd_config` on the server and `ssh_config` on the client (under `/etc/ssh/`). Or simply generate and copy a `ecdsa` (instead of `rsa`) key pair and see.

Comment: `sshd_config` from the remote is added. Kindly check.

Comment: Rather, paste `ssh -Q PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` from both sides

Comment: from both side, its giving `Unsupported query "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithm"`

Comment: You missed the `s`

Comment: Unsupported query "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms"

Comment: Oops sorry, looks like before 8.5 it's called `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`